# Difference between utility and helper in ember js?

Tags: ember.js

Can someone please explain the difference between utils and helper in Ember js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Helpers](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/writing-helpers/) are specifically for use within templates, though they *can* export their non-htmlbars-helper function for use outside of the template context (such as for unit testing)

[Utilities](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/service/) are generally pure functions that don't typically depend on any ember / framework code, and be unit tested without the app loading (as opposed to an integration or acceptance test).

Utilities have the ability to be extracted from your app and packaged as framework agnostic packages, whereas Helpers are specific to ember's templates.